# How correctly access member of array in C?

Tags: c

In my code FILES is struct.

```
typedef struct  {
  char name[64];
  char filename[64];
  long size; // file size
  long loaded; // after load of kernel loaded should be same value as size
  char * program;
} FILES;
```

files is array of type FILES.

```
FILES files[MAX_KERNELS_COUNT];
```

in function loadKernels I would like to access member of the array files via pointer.

```
bool loadKernels(const char * path, FILES * files, int count)
{
...
size = strlen(files[c].program);
printf("\n%ld\n",size);
size = sizeof(files[c].program);
printf("\n%ld\n",size);
...
}
```

I have problem there on the line with files[c].program . I know that I must access files like a pointer but how to do it correctly to obtain the length of the C string? I know something like (*files)[c].program is wrong.

Comment: You're already doing it correctly, and directly afterwards you do it incorrectly. To get the length of a string, you use `strlen`, to get the size *of the pointer* (not what it points to) you use `sizeof`.

Comment: How you obtain the length of the `string` has nothing to do with how you access the array, what the function recieves is a pointer to the first element of the array, so assuming `c < MAX_KERNELS_COUNT`, `size = strlen(files[c].program);` is correct provided `.program` points to a sequence of bytes all initialized and terminated with `'\0'`.

Comment: So it is correct,but I expected different result. This is why I thought that it was wrong: I expected the lenght of program to be 11000 bytes. But it has only 7 bytes. According Code::blocks watch tool the string is: 0x4c66b0 "\177ELF\001\001\001" ,,, it seems that there is some problem with my function.

Answer (score 1):

`files` is an array of `FILES`.

`files[c]` is thus of type `FILES`

`files[c].program` is thus of type `char *`.

so `strlen(files[c].program)` should give you what you want, i.e. the length of the string (as opposed to the size of the pointer). Note `strlen` will exclude the terminating `NUL`, i.e. the size of the string will be one byte longer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 size = strlen(files[c].program);
 printf("\n%ld\n",size);
 size = sizeof(files[c].program); //<-- Here you are using the sizeof. change this into strlen
 printf("\n%ld\n",size);
```

Sizeof gives you sizeof the given variable. It will not give you the string length.

Comment: It would make no sense to change the `sizeof` with `strlen`, the probably correct thing to do is to remove that line completely.

Answer (score 0):

> I have problem there on the line with files[c].program . I know that I
>   must access files like a pointer but how to do it correctly to obtain
>   the length of the C string? I know something like (*files)[c].program
>   is wrong.

**There is no string**

program is a pointer to somewhere outside the array.